# "Permission denied (publickey)." while trying to SSH into Amazon EC2

Tags: linux, ubuntu, amazon-web-services, ssh, amazon-ec2

I have an iPython installation on AWS, which I can access via the browser just fine.
When I try to ssh to the EC2 instance though, I get the following error:

```
Permission denied (publickey).
```

I have tried using my existing .pem key, as well by generating new keys, nothing has worked still.
These are the steps I have followed:

1. $ chmod 700 ~/.ssh
2. cp ~/desktop/aws/ipython.pem ~/.ssh/ipython.pem
3. chmod 600 ~/.ssh/ipython.pem
4. ssh -i ~/.ssh/ipython.pem ubuntu@50.174.xx.xx

On running the ssh command "ssh -i ~/.ssh/ipython.pem ubuntu@50.174.xx.xx -v", I get the following response:

```
OpenSSH_6.9p1, LibreSSL 2.1.8
debug1: Reading configuration data /Users/coffeeman/.ssh/config
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 20: Applying options for *
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 102: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to 50.174.xx.xx [50.174.xx.xx] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/coffeeman/.ssh/ipython.pem type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/coffeeman/.ssh/ipython.pem-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.9
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2.6
debug1: match: OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2.6 pat OpenSSH_6.6.1* compat 0x04000000
debug1: Authenticating to 50.174.xx.xx:22 as 'ubuntu'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com <implicit> none
debug1: kex: client->server chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com <implicit> none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:uBRsbvwsIcqNN7vUfzpIXd6n7W5cpyGyU0DutxEHJE8E
debug1: Host '50.174.xx.xx' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /Users/coffeeman/.ssh/known_hosts:10
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /Users/coffeeman/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/coffeeman/.ssh/ipython.pem
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey).
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your permissions are fine. What key was used to create the Ubuntu instance?

Comment: Clearly you didn't use the `ipython` key to launch the instance.

Comment: The same key named ipython.pem, that I downloaded from AWS itself.

Comment: Apologies, I don't understand what you mean by 'key to launch the instance'. I downloaded this key from AWS itself. I had a previous instance that I deleted, and that used a pem file that I already had on my system.

Comment: It is clear from the log that the ssh command cannot access the ipython.pem file. What happens when you try to simply cat the file?

Comment: Just ran 'cat ipython.pem' and this is the output:
`-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
QjywEzUehnQiGm9qKtNbPGYh0Kq2sdahtDZkwu7z4JkOmQDeE+ml+JHoYL7sCQKpI+qq8dJTH5UM
rnFfgFj6jRNSLehsp6zO+j1hP1+Vh+yEg2PVkY9JzjjMcZIMJhyVYTmRVtMmsgZ77SWi6u4+UMYe
Ni6cFyszHw824mxIVXVRDMvkQvlo7y6bfMxxUHIB2iL6mQyatVSKJwIDAQNNZ5RLeYudGkAi+3yHqzlwDatT55/Ut1+ssYRTPPEcmvDr/oZ2QtB2hl
N105hZqokCxWLhex5Sw19D33IgECgYEA6eDZutkl/i0UajP0fB9O03ChDX0gEt7uT3bgziVrJs5N
P969Ph4gIWmLc4eZ/GzcRZSOV3kGu2ls7hpw/QRwt457fkoSj4DSGee/yx
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----`

Comment: Dude, this is your PRIVATE key. I strongly suggest you remove your comment and generate a new key

Comment: It's a vastly shortened version of the private key. Not enough to regenerate anything of significance.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you didn't use this key to create your EC2 instance. Here's how to do it

- Go to the EC2 console
- Click on `Launch an instance`, and choose your OS, instance type, etc.
- You will get to this window

[image]

- Select `Create a new key pair` from the option list and give it a name, for instance **ipython**
- Click on `Download keypair`
- Store this in ~/.ssh/ipython.pem
- Connect to your instance via SSH using

  `ssh -i ~/.ssh/ipython.pem your-ip`

And everything should be fine! :)